# How to center content within a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a content that contains a table inside a div... But I cannot seem to work out how to do it...

Basically Id like to put some text next to a table, and center the table and the text to the page...

**The content I am trying to center:**

```
        <div style="background: purple; padding: 5px;">
            <div>
            <table style="float: left;">
                <tr>
                    <th>This</th>
                    <th>is</th>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>test</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <span style="background: yellow; margin-left: 15px; float: left;">This is a test</span>
        </div>
```

**What I have tried:**

```
    <div style="background: red; width: 100%; text-align: center">
        <div style="background: purple; padding: 5px;">
            <div>
            <table style="float: left;">
                <tr>
                    <th>This</th>
                    <th>is</th>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>test</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <span style="background: yellow; margin-left: 15px; float: left;">This is a test</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If someone would be able to tell me what I am doing wrong here it would be greatly apprectiated.

Comment: Give the parent `div` (i.e. with purple background) a width, and then use `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: My work proxy doesnt allow jsfiddle... sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

You can center elements using `text-align:center` if they are `inline` or `inline-block`. If we remove the floats and sit them next to each other using `display:inline-block` on the `<table>`, this method can be used.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/ruFrw/3/)

**CSS**

```
table {
    display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background: purple; padding: 5px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>This</th>
            <th>is</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>test</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <span style="background: yellow; margin-left: 15px;">This is a test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The text in the span displays under the table in IE, which is not what I am after sorry. The text needs to be next to the table.

Answer (score 1):

you can provide ID to inner div say inner and say outer to top div:

```
#outer{width:100%}
#inner{float:none;margin:0 auto;display:table;}
```

if you find any problem let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/7TEqW/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>TABLE TEXT</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <span>SPAN TEXT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #999;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Ok the text is next to the table, but the text and the table are not centered on the page...

Comment: Yes they are, if you take a screenshot of the jsfiddle and measure the left and right margins in Photoshop you'll see they're the same. Well left margin is 446px and right margin 445px but that's down to the width of the elements. Those px values will obviously change depending on your screen size and/or the size of the jsfiddle pane.

Comment: @BillyMoat - In IE they are not, which browser are you using?

Comment: Tested in FF, Chrome and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` and try adding `margin:0 auto`

```
.wrap{
background: purple; padding: 5px;    
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative
}
table{
    background:pink;
    margin:0 auto
}

span{
    background: yellow; margin-left: 15px;
        margin:0 auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KetEC/)**

Answer (score 0):

Put the desired content inside a 
`<p style="text-align: center;">`
element, and it will be horizontally centered.